# my swipe tabs change to an unwanted vertical mode

Tags: android, tabs

On my phones (htc/samsung) in portrait mode the tabs shows nicely side by side. As soon as I move to landscape mode, I only have one tab on which I need to click to have the tabs all showing as a vertical menu. It is due to the length of the tab name: tab's name under 7 char are showing nicely. The only difference I see is that in portrait mode, the tabs appear under the action bar, where in landscape mode it appears at the level of the action bar. I hope I'm clear!

Here is my code for the creation of the tabs:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    tabPagerAdapter = new tabpager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabPagerAdapter);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
```

I've googled through the doc but I can't find anything on how to fix this.

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: this is an inbuild feature for the acitonbar navigation mode, that when there is enough space it will automatically adjust it. You should possibly use `PagerTitleStrip` to acheive the effect since `NavigationMode` is depericated

Comment: if I understand right it is a child view to insert to provide more info to the tab?

Comment: isn't there another method? I don't want to add another layer. I just want to ad a tab's name of about 10 char.

Comment: I made more test. It works pretty well in my app. Many thanks for the advise!